# Apply a function over many shapefiles

Tags: r, gis, plyr, shapefile

I want to apply a function, either one that I have written, or one from a package such as the `gArea` function (e.g. `gArea('shapefile')`) from the `rgeos` package, across a list of shapefiles that I have imported.

I imported the files like this:

```
data <- list.files (getwd() , pattern="shp")
```

I have tried using methods using functions such as `lapply` etc once I have tried amalgamating the files by using `as.list`, `as.data.frame` etc but with no luck. Functions applied to single imported shapefiles work fine, but obviously no good for serioues throughput.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
sapply(lapply(list.files(pattern="*.shp"), readShapePoly), gArea)
```

Comment: Is there a thread that deals with how to bring in the names of the shapefiles in into the list?

Comment: you could do something like this: `cbind(list.files(pattern="*.shp"),  sapply(lapply(list.files(pattern="*.shp"), readShapePoly), gArea))`

Answer (score 0):

In the line of @jmsigner's answer, I would use `ldply` from the plyr package:

```
require(rgeos)
require(plyr)

shp_paths = list.files(pattern = "shp")
shp_files = llply(shp_paths, readShapePoly)
areas = ldply(shp_files, gArea)
```

I believe that `ldply` also includes the shapefile names in the resulting `areas` data.frame. In addition, `plyr` functions include a builtin progress bar (see `.progress`), and can parallelized easily.